# Hibernate: Join table to a join table annotation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

How do you create an annotation for the following case:

```
Table A
id
name

Table B
id
name

Table C
id
name

Table AB
a_id
b_id

Table ABC
id
a_id
b_id
c_id
name
```

How can you represent table ABC on hibernate using annotations?

Table AB is not an object it is used as a table join between tables A and B.

The annotation for A and B would look something like this:

For A:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="AB",  
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id")},  
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id")})  
private Set bs;
```

For B:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="AB",  
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id")},  
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id")})  
private Set as;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not use @ManyToMany ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have done something like that :

A:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "AB", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID",
        referencedColumnName = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID",
        referencedColumnName = "ID"))
private List<B> bs;
```

Same for B.

ABC:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
private A a;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
private B b;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "C_ID")
private C c;
```

Comment: Hi Nunien, will try this, later today, and will mark it as answer if it works! Thank you